# Error 404 after deploy angular 14 app on IIS as WebSite

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, web-config

I Create simple basic Angular 14 application and I want to deploy it to IIS server.

What I added to basic app is:

```
// in app.component
<h1>THIS IS ANGULAR TEST APP</h1>

// test of paths
<img src="../resources/Samolot.jpg" alt="asd">
<img src="/src/resources/icon - Copy.png" alt="asd">
<img src="./../assets/icon - Copy.png" alt="asd">
<img src="./../assets/Samolot.jpg" alt="asd" width="400px" height="400px">

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and one component (TestComponent)

```
<h1>This is test component</h1>
```

```
Routing:

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "another", component: TestComponent },
];
```

Steps for deploy :

1. ng build --configuration production --base-href /testapp/
2. IIS > SITES > AddWebsite > add Site name : testapp
3. Set physical path of project
4. I have URL Rewrite installed on my iis

I also add following web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/testapp/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Despite of above steps I'm still having 404 error, when I wan't to get http://localhost:4200/testapp

Fun fact is that when I use

ng build --configuration production (without base href)
and set web.config to "/" in action all works perfect

above configuration works if I will "AddApplication despite of add web website"

where the problem can be?

Comment: That's simply because `http://localhost:4200/testapp` is not the URL to access an IIS site. Read more from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis and see where the misunderstanding comes from. `--base-href /testapp/` shouldn't be used for sites, neither `url="/testapp/"` in rewrite rule.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @LexLi yes, that was the problem, my misunderstanding between using wep application and new web site,